# Using Illustrator image for custom animation using C++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, adobe-illustrator, animated

I have a vectorized Adobe Illustrator image that I would like to animate using custom xyz input (in this case simulated plot points that I would like to visualize over time, using a hand drawn picture/wireframe model) from e.g. a c++ program or perhaps even javascript application. Is there any (fairly straightforward) strategy to achieve this? E.g. using open GL or some other (open source) tool?

Comment: What you're looking for a graphics library. If you want to write C++, you could try SDL2 - probably easier than doing it via OpenGL. You could also try PyGame which is python. HTML5 might also be OK. Depends on how comfortable you are in a particular language. Can you offer a few more details about your background and the project your doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw vectorized images you would need to use vector image renderer. The easiest way to do this is to use [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) since it has support vector drawing (one of the best) and really strong scripting language to do all sorts of things (anymate stuff based on input, etc) even 3d graphics.

The hard way of doing this is to use a custom library in c++ do draw vector grapics in opengl or directx. I can only speak of [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/textweb.pl?path=geekstuff/gameswf.txt) (opensource player for flash files) or [scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform). There two have support for swf files exported by flash. If you only need a renderer without any animation then there should be plenty of libraries out there (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176637/render-a-vector-graphic-svg-in-c) thread)